# Connection does not correctly set catalog using HikariCP

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hikaricp

I'm trying out HikariCP as a replacement for C3P0. Everything is working out good so far, but one of the problems I'm having is with setting the catalog on a connection.

Depending on the account being used, I need to look up the account's schema (based on a thread local property holding the current account Id) and set the connection catalog. I was able to do this with C3P0, but with HikariCP every connection in the pool seems to stick to the first catalog it gets set to.

```
public class AccountScopedDataSource extends DelegatingDataSource {
    public Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = super.getConnection();
        String accountId = getAccountId();
        String catalog = getAccountSchema(accountId);
        connection.setCatalog(catalog);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7 (mysql-connector-java 5.4.1), Spring Boot and Hibernate 5.2.9.

Any help is much appreciated!

To add a bit more info - I have tried to debug this, and it seems like the correct SQL and catalog is being set on the connection each time, it just isn't being used correctly

Comment: HikariCP does not support this.  In truth, neither does C3P0, it just looks like it does.  Calling setCatalog() causes MySQL to dump the connection under the covers and reconnect, defeating the point of pooling. I recommend creating a map of catalog to HikariCP pool instances.  Users have reported successfully running thousands of pool instances in a single JVM.

Comment: Ah interesting, never knew setting the catalog worked that way with MySql - I'll have to give the multiple pool approach a go. At the minute I am using Hikari for our static schema and C3P0 for the 'dynamic' schema switching - would like to switch to Hikari for both as it definitely performed a lot better in my initial tests

Comment: Just so you know, PostgreSQL also performs a disconnect and reconnect on setCatalog().

Comment: @brettw Is this still true? I ask because I just tried 5.0.1 and setCatalog() seems to work. On a related note I did look at creating a pool instance per catalog but that could result in the mysql requiring a pretty max connection (at least 1 per catalog). In any case can you please confirm if setCatalog() has changed since your comment almost 6 years ago...